# Appending struct by reference to an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pass-by-reference

How can I implement a function in C++ that appends a struct instance to an array by reference? So that after appending a struct stored in a variable to the array, this variable can be used further to change the instance of array.

pseudocode:

```
struct St{
 int x
}

St* arr;
St a = {0};
append a to arr;
a.x = 1;
//expecting arr[0].x = 1
```

Here is the C++ code with the film example (see comments describing the problem):

```
struct Film{
    int id;
    char* name;
};

void add_film(Film *&films, int &size, Film &film){
    if (size == 0)
        films = new Film[1];
    else
    {
        Film *tmp = new Film[size + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            tmp[i] = films[i];
        }
        delete[]films;
        films = tmp;
    }
    films[size] = film;
    film = films[size]; //how to reassign passed film object to a new object in array?
    size++;
}

int main(){
    Film *films = nullptr;
    int size = 0;
    Film film = {1, "Name1"};
    add_film(films, size, film);
    film.name = "Name2";
    std::cout << films[0].name;  //output: "Name1", expected: "Name2"
}
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `new`/`delete` use standard classes instead, e.g. `std::vector` in your case. Second, why not other way around? I.e. first append/allocate object to list, then get its reference?

Comment: This is not possible with the given types. Something that could come close would be to use an array of film pointers (or better `std::unique_ptr<Film>`s) which would allow you to return a reference to new `Film` object that stays the same even if the array grows. I strongly recommend creating a `class`/`struct` managing the film data though which would be the usual way dealing with releasing memory; note that the array allocated last is never freed by your code which is a bad thing if you ever plan on using multiple film lists in a single program (keyword memory leak)

Comment: @fabian Its possible, using `std::reference_wrapper`, but usually this is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Appending struct by reference to an array in C++

There are two problems with this:

1. There cannot be arrays of references in C++.
2. There is no way to append to an array. The size of an array is a constant. There is no way to add or remove elements.

An issue with your attempted solution is that you have an array of Films, and not an array of references. This isn't very surprising, as problem 1 described above states there are no such thing as arrays of references. The solution is simple however: Use pointers instead of references. Technically, you could use a reference wrapper instead, but a pointer is often simpler.

You've basically figured out the solution to 2. already. What you're doing is creating a new array, copying the old elements from the old array into the new one, and destroying the old array. That's a good approach in general, but there are a number of problems with this trivial implementation:

- Bare owning pointers are unsafe and hard to use.
- Reallocating and copying the entire array on every append is very expensive.

Former can be solved by using the RAII idiom, and latter can be solved by separating the storage of the objects from the creation of the objects, and by growing the storage by a constant factor i.e. geometrically. There is no need to implement such RAII container though, since the standard library has you covered. It's called `std::vector`.

In conclusion: You can use `std::vector<Film*>`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The use of `std::vector` is not allowed in my project :) Can I change my `add_film` function, so that it returns the newly created struct instance of the array so that I can use it one-line like `Film film1 = add_film(...)` instead of using two commands `add_film(...); Film film1 = films[0]`? Declaring function return type `Film&` and returning `return films[size]` doesn't work. Thx